# Counterfactual Quantum Computation is Really Weird

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQIfSrRBEgw a high level 'popular' introduction to Counterfactual Quantum Computation is provided.

The only part that seemed to 'come out of the blue' was the statement at 10:54 that says : "So we know that the answer is 'yes' without ever running the computer" (when measuring a photon at detector D1, with a classical computer being interrogated). The reasoning seemed to be that, as the measured photon at detector D1 can't have gone through the computer, then the computer need not have run.

I'm guessing that this is a simplification, since the wave function still needs to go to the computer. In addition this is the first time that a non-running computer is mentioned, and the distribution of photon measurements with a non running computer would need to be determined to ensure that it doesn't produce results associated with a running computer (e.g. when not operating it could open the photon path through the computer, which is the same as a running computer with answer 'yes' would produce).

**My question is** : Would it be possible to fill in the 'missing' reasoning to explain why the computer would not need to run and still imply that a photon measured at detector D1 means it correctly answers 'yes' to the outcome of a computation, had the computation been performed (in the setup in the video)?

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907007v2

Comment: Sounds a lot like [Elitzur-Vaidman bomb experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester).